# How does daily Google Apps Script services quota limit apply?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I have few questions regarding [Google Apps Script Quota limit](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard):

1) How are the daily limits applicable - per Script/Per User/Per domain for a container bound Script?
eg- UrlFetch Total Bytes is limited to 100mB per day for Google Apps Business Edition - 
Does that mean

- All users of the domain will be accounted against a single limit of 100mB OR
- Limit would apply per script per user OR
- Limit would apply per user across all Scripts of that individual user?

2) How would the daily limit apply if the script is deployed as web App which is deployed to run in the context of user accessing the web App?

- All users of the domain will be accounted against a single limit of 100mB (any other script the users are using will also account against the single limit of 100mB) OR

  - each user will be accounted against his/her own quota limit for this script only? OR
  - any user of any domain accesses the script, aggregation of all the usage unit would be accounted against the script's limit of 100MB?

3) When does the limits gets reset (eg: 12:00 AM, user time zone or Google Account Primary Admin time zone or Script owner time zone)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Per user (this has been asked before here, find the post for more details)

2) Discounted against the users that run the script if you publish it as running as the user.

3) Don't think this is published. Your code shouldn't depend on this. Might change in the future as Google adds more datacenters.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the link pointed by here? Also, if I understand you correctly - if a user has multiple scripts usage units by each script would be aggregated and accounted against daily limit or each script will have its own limit for the user?

Comment: Im lazy to look it up but I know it was anwered before. And like my answer said, its per user not per script. Cheers.

Comment: A script can have a maximum number of triggers, a maximum size of ScriptProperties and an overall maximum ScriptDb. These are storage maxima and not performance/ api call limits.

Comment: there are also rate limits per script and other limits, but daily quotas are per user regarding script running time or urlfetch

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me.

Some of my scripts can still run, while other's don't. Why?

Comment: likely because those scripts use a different set of APIs, and each API has its own set of quotas.