# Quota limits after Google Apps Script deployed as web app

Tags: google-apps-script

Probably this question has already been asked here. But I didn't get any reference.

Once I deploy a script as web app, the quota limits of APIs will be different for each user or they will all start consuming a single quota limit ?

The deployment settings are as follows:

[image]

Can you point me to a link which proofs above ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @HemangiPithava It is no where mentioned in that url.

Comment: you can try Google App Engine if you wish, enjoy the 600K+ url fetch quota and awesome other features!

Comment: @NitinDhomse I got my answer. Asked in G+ GAS forum and experts said it is per user basis. Check his comment here. https://plus.google.com/+HariShankarDas/posts/4cvmzVGhCyE

Answer (score 0):

For every Google account (user) has a separate API quota but, you are saying that your app script is deployed that means, it has been deployed from the particular user's account so, in this case every Google API hit quota (like sending email, url fetches, language translation etc.) will be used from the user account who have deployed the script although different users are using it.

Comment: So lets say, There are 10 users for my app. The URL Fetch calls quota limit is 20,000/day. This means only 2000 calls (Just an average) are applicable to each user ?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: Do you have any link which states that ?

Comment: Actually, there is no any doc which explaining this scenario, but this is true as per my hands on experience on app script.

Comment: Forgot to mention the settings. Updated the question.

Comment: This thing is very clear in the Google doc that, every user account has a separate quota and the script is deployed by a single user, no extra quota is provided by Google for deployed script, I observed / experienced this scenario, you can also try the sample script, use the Trigger to hit particular API like url fetch  and log your count and handle api quota exceeded exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161425/discussion-between-hari-das-and-nitin-dhomse).

Comment: I got the one answer provided by Google developer expert, in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875014/how-does-daily-google-apps-script-quota-limit-apply, The reason for the this, which is not provided in any official Google doc is due to a very strait forward scenario and I experienced this practically, trust me!

Comment: Now read the 2nd point written by Zig Mandel in that link. It contradicts to what you said.

Comment: That may be true, but read the whole that answer and comments below that, ultimately the conclusion is what I'm  saying, I think hands on over the this scenario will be better to understand the truth.

Comment: I read everything. Can you mention a section which you want to point to ?